# Wordpress Functions in CodeIgniter? (Controllers, Models and Views)

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, integration

Is there any way to access WordPress functions in CodeIgnighter? Basically I am running a website entirely using WordPress but I need to build a custom add-on system that needs to be separate from WordPress (so not a plugin). Thanks to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829990/codeigniter-wordpress-integration)

I can get WP functions working in views but not in controllers or models.
My folder structure is WordPress installed in site root then the CodeIgnighter in WordPress: *root/wordpress/codeignighter*

I need this as I want to use WordPress user functions so people can use the CI system with their WP accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was an error on my behalf I forgot to declare some global variables as the linked solution clearly states. My bad