# How to use Codeigniter functions in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter-2

I would like to integrate the wordpress blog into codigniter site. I found one solution to use CI functions into wordpress but it didn't work. I would like to add ci header into wordpress blog.

[found the sollution from this](http://thedaylightstudio.com/blog/2010/06/16/codeigniter-and-wordpress-integration)

[image]

In above picture it shows me a error. It's related to path issue.

Comment: files are missing, copy them properly and why would you use CI with wordpress? it is going to be hectic soon...

Comment: Actually it's client's requirement to use ci header into wordpress blog. And these files are not missing. constants.php  is loacted at application/config directory.

Comment: the path is correct that means right? and what do you mean by CI header in WP?

Comment: I have a website in codeigniter and clients wants to use the header part of the website into wordpress blog. Is it possible to write just $CI->load->view('header') in wordpress? And I think the path isn't correct. It should located to application/config directory.

Comment: Both are developed on different frameworks, core php will be very helpful here..you cant use  $CI->load->view('header') because it would run since the wordpress doesn't know about the code igniter framework. why do you customize the header of your wordpress blog?

Comment: It's requirement. If a user log in into website and visit a blog then he /she should know about it. And it's easy to directly go back to the website from header. So I want the header of a website into blog. But in header I had used some CI functions so It creates a problem. Is there any way to do it the same?

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829990/codeigniter-wordpress-integration, It may help you.