# Using Code Igniter active record in Wordpress

Tags: codeigniter, wordpress

Need to move some code from Code Igniter to Wordpress. It is heavily using CodeIgniter's db classes to handle the database. I would like to use them like this, instead of translating to WP's wpdb.

Is there any way of using Code Igniter active record/db classes and keep the nice CI db usage in Wordpress?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WordPress 3.3 and above, then you can make use of the following library [WordPressIgniter](https://github.com/dynamodan/wordpressigniter)

Usually, it's not as straight forward as you think, because both of them have their own code structure. But many have tried it and are successful. It depends on what features you want to use and to what depth.

Following links may come handy for you:

1. [SO - CI WodrePress Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829990/codeigniter-wordpress-integration)
2. http://www.marketingadept.com/blog/integrating-codeigniter-and-wordpress/