# Codeigniter 3.1.6 change in app directory folder redirecting/routing

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an app built on CI which was hosted at domain.com and now I have installed Wordpress on main domain and moved CI to domain.com/folder. I set the base URL to domain.com/folder but it's not working. All folders were in root directory public_html.

Here's image of folders (don't know if it will be helpful):
[image: Folders]

Controller that loads landing page:

```
public function index()
  {
    $this->load->view('client/home_view');
  }

public function logout()
  {
    $client_id = $this->session->userdata('client_id');
    $this->db->where('id', $client_id);
    $data = $this->db->get('client');
    $workforce = $data->row();
    $country_name = $workforce->country_name;

    if($country_name == 'Estonia')
      {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('client_logged_in');
        redirect('Random');
      }
    else
      {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('client_logged_in');
        redirect('Client');
      }
  }
```

Comment: it's the other way around, but might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829990/codeigniter-wordpress-integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question need a litle bit more details, but please check these points.
Also please send screenshot and more information about "*it's not working*"

1. Double check your base_url in application/config.php. It's often problem.
2. Check your defaulut controller
3. Check .htaccess files. If you can't find something wrong or strange - try to delete all existing htaccess files and request domain.com/folder

Comment: Thanks! I checked my .htaccess file. WordPress had overwrite the CI .htaccess file.