# PHP Slim & WordPress Integration

Tags: php, wordpress, slim

I have a simple PHP app built using Slim v4 framework. In a nutshell, the app consists of two pages only and it provides a REST API:

```
<?php
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
use Slim\Views\Twig;
use Slim\Views\TwigMiddleware;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
// Instantiate App
$app = AppFactory::create();
// Create Twig
$twig = Twig::create('/../templates', ['cache' => false]);
// Add Twig-View Middleware
$app->add(TwigMiddleware::create($app, $twig));
// Add error middleware
$app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true);

// Add routes
$app->get('/page1', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $view = Twig::fromRequest($request);
    return $view->render($response, 'page1.html');
});
$app->get('/page2', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $view = Twig::fromRequest($request);
    return $view->render($response, 'page2.html');
});

$app->post('/process', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    // do some work
    // put something in db
    // redirect to page2
});

$app->run();
```

On the other hand, I also have a full WordPress application. Both apps run on the same local serve. This is the file structure:

```
my_slim_app
├── public
│   └── index.php
├── vendor
└── templates
wp-content
wp-includes
wp-admin
```

My goal is to integrate these apps in the following way:

1. I want to be able to use Wordpress php functions inside the Slim app (I intend to do this by including wp_load.php in the Slim app)
2. I want to integrate Slim app's routing system with wordpress routing. I am not sure what should I define as the base path in the Slim app. Also, I am not sure how many .htaccess files do I need and what should be their content.

In the end, assuming I manage to integrate the apps this way, is this even the right approach? This is the simplest way I could think of, but I am not sure if it would be better to just rewrite the Slim app as a custom WordPress plugin or integrate it in a custom page template.

I took inspiration for this kind of integration from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829990/codeigniter-wordpress-integration).

Comment: Maybe try writing some WP plug-in to display Slim pages instead of making zombie framework that will be nightmare to maintain. Or if just show twig templates: https://wordpress.org/plugins/timber-library/

Comment: @Justinas Thank you for your comment! You're right about displaying the pages, it would be easier to just write or use a WP plugin. I'm more concerned about how to  integrate other HTTP request handlers (like POST request handler) from Slim to WordPress.

Comment: @v.st4mb0lic I mean there probably is a way to do this, but I don't want to rewrite everything if I don't have to. The question was more about would this zombie framework actually work :)

Comment: "I want to integrate Slim app's routing system with wordpress routing" - What exactly do you mean by "integrate"? If you install Slim in a subfolder, the standard Apache/Nginx/IIS rewrite rules should automatically be able to route requests. Do you want WordPress to be "aware" of Slim somehow?